# How to read a file with uneven spaces as delimiter

Tags: r, tidyverse, readfile

I have the following string (actually it's from a file):

```
cfile <- "  ILE   800   A   MET     1   B\n  ASP   797   A   PHE    38   B\n  GLY   156   A   ASP     5   B\n"
```

How can I read that string into a tibble or data frame, resulting in this (by hand):

```
X1.   X2    X3  X4.     X5. X6
<chr>  <dbl> ......         <chr>
ILE   800   A   MET     1   B
ASP   797   A   PHE    38   B
GLY   156   A   ASP     5   B
```

With this:

```
readr::read_delim(cfile, col_names = FALSE)
```

I get this which is not what I want:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 20
  X1    X2    X3    X4    X5       X6 X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15     X16   X17
  <lgl> <lgl> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 NA    NA    ILE   NA    NA      800 NA    NA    A     NA    NA    MET   NA    NA    NA       NA     1
2 NA    NA    ASP   NA    NA      797 NA    NA    A     NA    NA    PHE   NA    NA    NA       38    NA
3 NA    NA    GLY   NA    NA      156 NA    NA    A     NA    NA    ASP   NA    NA    NA       NA     5
```

Not that there's uneven space delimiter, in the input file.

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 2):

```
read.table(text = cfile)
   V1  V2 V3  V4 V5 V6
1 ILE 800  A MET  1  B
2 ASP 797  A PHE 38  B
3 GLY 156  A ASP  5  B
```

Other ways:

```
data.table::fread(cfile)
    V1  V2 V3  V4 V5 V6
1: ILE 800  A MET  1  B
2: ASP 797  A PHE 38  B
3: GLY 156  A ASP  5  B

readr::read_table(cfile, col_names = FALSE)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  X1       X2 X3    X4       X5 X6   
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 ILE     800 A     MET       1 B    
2 ASP     797 A     PHE      38 B    
3 GLY     156 A     ASP       5 B   

readr::read_delim(cfile, delim = ' ', col_names = FALSE,trim_ws = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  X1       X2 X3    X4       X5 X6   
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 ILE     800 A     MET       1 B    
2 ASP     797 A     PHE      38 B    
3 GLY     156 A     ASP       5 B   

read.table(textConnection(cfile))
   V1  V2 V3  V4 V5 V6
1 ILE 800  A MET  1  B
2 ASP 797  A PHE 38  B
3 GLY 156  A ASP  5  B
```